# Font recognized in Windows XP but not Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, fonts

I've created a font namely `ROAD.TTF` for XP using software named "Softy", but when I install my font `ROAD.TTF`  to Windows 7, it seems that the system doesn't recognize the "characters" starting from character map  129 (and through 157).

Why doesn't Windows 7 recognize my characters?

Answer (score 0):

If it works in Windows-XP but not Windows-7 I would guess the Font file has a fault that XP tolerates.

### Softy

It seems to me that softy has limited documentation that hasn't been maintained recently, [it's web page](http://users.breathe.com/l-emmett/) talks about nothing later than Windows NT.

> It runs under Windows (3.1, 95, 98, NT), and requires a 386 or better.

This makes me wonder if the author has perhaps not tested it on Windows 7 - perhaps there is some quirk of Windows-7 that the author has not accommodated? Perhaps softy has some quirk that needs to be dealt with by the developer?

### TTF file format

Perhaps there is an issue in the TTF cmap table for your font.

See http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter08

> The ‘cmap’ table consists of a set of mapping subtables for different technologies and architectures.
>
> Each mapping subtable has two numbers associated with it: the platform id and the encoding id.

It might be useful to check this.

### FontForge

I would try opening your TTF file in another editor such as [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) - perhaps it will identify some problem?

Comment: thanks for the answer @redgrittybrick! I've surfed the net and found few font generating software but all of them are for sale. I've also tried some trials but in order to produce a .TTF file, you must first avail their product (e.g High Logic font generator). I'm afraid to purchase any of them because of the software conflict on Windows 7. my question is, is there's a free font software generator for Windows 7 similar to softy?

Comment: @progy: did you try the product I mentioned at the end of my answer? "FontForge -- An outline font editor that lets you create your own postscript, truetype, opentype, cid-keyed, multi-master, cff, svg and bitmap (bdf, FON, NFNT) fonts" There is no fee or charge for downloading and using it.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick the "Cygwin" requirement takes alot of time to install but im looking forward on using it, i'm just wondering if you know other software that can be used, thanks by the way ^^